# Saturation,Example, uncountable cardinality

Tags: examples-counterexamples, cardinals, model-theory

[Here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007212001558), in the example 1.0.27, how can I see that if $\lambda>\aleph_0$, then every model
$M\in K_{\lambda^+}$ is saturated over $\lambda$?How do I use uncountability of $\lambda$?

Comment: By the way, your questions would probably be better received if you gave more context and motivation. Expecting the reader to open up a paper to find all of the relevant definitions (and probably to be surprised to find we're talking about AECs and Galois types, instead of elementary classes and first-order types!) is not the most polite way to ask a question. I answered, but also downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show it's saturated by figuring out what all the Galois types are (there aren't many in this example!), and checking that they're all realized.

Let's say an element which satisfies all the $P_n$ is central. The point is that if a model is uncountable of size $\lambda$, then it must contain a central element (actually $\lambda$-many), so you know which $E$-class all the central elements are in. Over a countable model with no central elements, there are two central Galois types, which can't both be realized in the same model. This is the only obstruction to saturation.